# Distance between parallel planes.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some trouble with a question while preparing for a test.

I would love to get some strategies on how to solve it.

Here's the question:

```
Given two parallel planes π1 and π2 with a distance 1 between them.
Plane π1 passes throw dot A(0,0,6). Plane π2 passes throw dots B(1,-8,0) and C(-15,0,0)
Find the equations of both planes.
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the plane through the two points,
its equation is

$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are determined up to a multiplicative factor.
Now you have three equations:

$$-15a+d=0$$
$$x-8y+d=0$$ for passing through B and C. Third you have the equation for the distance between a plane $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ and a point $A$ now just solve these three equations.